# How to find enum's value from a key?

Tags: typescript, enums

category and status are **enums**. In the C# they look like this:

```
public enum PropertyStatus
{
    ForSale,
    ForRent
}
```

The same enum is like this in the typescript code

```
export enum PropertyStatus {
   ForSale = "For Sale",
   ForRent = "For Rent"
}
```

the backend sends a json object that looks like

```
{
    "id": "2b719b1c-306d-4482-ad55-0d9f4d08294b",
    //..
    "category": 0,
    "status": 0,
},
```

This is how I'm trying to map the enums coming from the backend to the enums in the angular code.

```
mapEnumValues(d: any): PropertyItem {
    const categoryKeys = Object.keys(PropertyCategory);
    const statusKeys = Object.keys(PropertyStatus);
    for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        let elt = d[i];
        elt.category = categoryKeys[elt.category];
        elt.status = statusKeys[elt.status];
    }
    return d;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting only the keys, i.e. `ForSale` and `ForRent`. What I want is the value, i.e. `For Sale` and `For Rent`.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value from the key like this:

```
mapEnumValues(d: any): PropertyItem {
    const categoryKeys = Object.keys(PropertyCategory);
    const statusKeys = Object.keys(PropertyStatus);
    for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        let elt = d[i];
        elt.category = PropertyStatus[categoryKeys[elt.category]];
        elt.status = PropertyStatus[statusKeys[elt.status]];
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: getting this error: `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof PropertyStatus'.`

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to map statuses, because you can use enum as map itself.

Write below enum:

```
export enum PropertyStatus {
   ForSale,
   ForRent,
}
```

enum without values takes default values which are numbers 0, 1, 2 etc.

Now, only one thing you need is define interface from backend:

```
interface BackendResponse {
  id: string;
  status: PropertyStatus;
  ...
}
```

Now you can map data as you want, with status already properly typed.
Basicly 0 == PropertyStatus.ForSale

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. It stopped complaining about `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof PropertyStatus'.`

Also, it's returning the `For Sale` and `For Rent` instead of `ForSale` and `ForRent`.

```
mapEnumValues(d: any): PropertyItem[] {
    const categoryValues = Object.values(PropertyCategory);
    const statusValues = Object.values(PropertyStatus);
    const arr: PropertyItem[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        let elt: PropertyItem = { ...d[i] };
        elt.category = categoryValues[d[i].category];
        elt.status = statusValues[d[i].status];
        arr.push(elt);
    }
    return arr;
}
```